# Using python-redis with multiprocessing module

Tags: python, redis, multiprocessing, connection-pooling

I'm very new to the python redis module and am looking for an efficient way to pool connections while using python multiprocessing module.  My code is as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import Queue
import os
import time
import redis

def _process_messages_parallel(messages):
    processes=[mp.Process(target=_process_message, args=[message]) for message in messages]

    for process in processes:
        process.daemon=False
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()


def _process_message(message):
    organization=message['organization']

    #get value associated with `organization` key from redis
    result=get_val_from_redis(organization)

    #process result

#assume local redis instance for now.
def get_val_from_redis(organization,host='localhost',port='6379'):
    conn=redis.StrictRedis(host=host,port=port,db=db,retry_on_timeout=retry_on_timeout) 
    return conn.get(organization)


if __name__=="__main__":
    messages=[{'organization':'org1'},{'organization':'org2'},{'organization':'org3'},...{'organization':'orgN'}]
    process_articles=mp.Process(target=_process_messages_parallel,args=[messages])
    process_articles.daemon=False 
    process_articles.start()
    process_articles.join()
```

Here essentially I would like to re-use the same connection pool between the different processes created by the `_process_messages_parallel` function. Could someone please suggest a good way to do it? A simple solution might be to create a module scope redis connection pool, or a function scope redis connection pool but my concern is how the python module/ or the python function is shared between different processes. If a separate copy of the object is created for each process, then it beats the purpose of the connection pool?

Comment: You should not (and probably cannot) share the connection pool between processes. Just use a per-process pool that will limit the number of connections in each process to the minimum.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer hmm that's what I have done currently. But not too satisfied with that solution though. If the processes are short lived, (which they are in my case) and are created and destroyed fairly regularly, I'm guessing the expense of creation of each connection to the redis instance adds up to be pretty significant.

Comment: so refactor your code that the processes are long lived with a process pool and a queue